# How to read numeric from binary data, crossplatform (C/C++)?

Tags: android, c++, ios, cross-platform

I have raw binary data blocks (actually, `CBOR`-encoded). To read numeric I use common form like:

```
template <typename T> // T can be uint64_t, double, uint32_t, etc...
auto read(const uint8_t *ptr) -> T {
    return *((T *)(ptr)); // all endianess-aware functions will be performed later
}
```

This solution works on `x86/x86_64` PC and `arm/arm64` iOS.
But, on `arm/armv7` Android with `clang` compiler on default release optimization level (`-Os`) i receive `SIGBUS` with code `1` (unaligned read) for types, larger then one byte. I fix that problem with another solution:

```
template <typename T>
auto read(const uint8_t *ptr) -> T {
    union {
        uint8_t buf[sizeof(T)];
        T value;
    } u;
    memcpy(u.buf, ptr, sizeof(T));
    return u.value;
}
```

Is there any platform-independent solution, that will not impact performance?

Comment: I think that's probably as good as you will get.

Comment: Use proper (de)serialisation instead of these undefined behaviour reinterpretations. You ran into some problems already, there can be more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*caveat* - this answer assumes that the integer representation of the machine is little-endian, as does the question.

The *only* platform-independent and correct way is to use memcpy. You don't need a union.

Don't worry about efficiency. memcpy is a magic function, and the compiler will 'do the right thing'.

example when compiled for x86:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T>
auto read(const uint8_t *ptr) -> T {
  T result;
  std::memcpy(&result, ptr, sizeof(T));
    return result;
}

extern const uint8_t* get_bytes();
extern void emit(std::uint64_t);

int main()
{
  auto x = read<std::uint64_t>(get_bytes());
  emit(x);

}
```

yields assembler:

```
main:
        subq    $8, %rsp
        call    get_bytes()
        movq    (%rax), %rdi         ; note - memcpy utterly elided
        call    emit(unsigned long)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
```

note: endian-ness

You can make this solution truly portable by adding a runtime endian-ness check. In reality, the check will be elided as the compiler will see through it:

```
constexpr bool is_little_endian()
{
    short int number = 0x1;
    char *numPtr = (char*)&number;
    return (numPtr[0] == 1);
}


template <typename T>
auto read(const uint8_t *ptr) -> T {
  T result = 0;
  if (is_little_endian())
  {
    std::memcpy(&result, ptr, sizeof(result));
  }
  else
  {
    for (T i = 0 ; i < sizeof(T) ; ++i)
    {
      result += *ptr++ << 8*i;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

The resulting machine code is unchanged:

```
main:
        subq    $8, %rsp
        call    get_bytes()
        movq    (%rax), %rdi
        call    emit(unsigned long)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
```

Comment: Nonsense! The only compliant and platform-independent way is seerialisation with bitshifts! `memcpy` does not care about endianess or representation.

Comment: Endianess is not an issue, since all the compilers i need have intrinsic to convert byte order. When there is no intrinsic, i fallback to bitshifts.

Comment: @olaf I am aware of the endian-ness issue, and  have assumed that the OP knows about it to. I was addressing the issue of transferring a byte stream to an integer. I'll add a caveat to the answer.

Comment: @Olaf updated, and an endian-proof solution added with the benefit that it's still 100% efficient on a little-endian x86.

Comment: @SBKarr: What is the problem using proper serialisation in the first place? A good compiler will not generate worse code than for the "hackish" approach with reinterpretation, but there is no need for testing, nor other target-dependent stuff.

Comment: @Olaf Out of curiosity, when you say "proper serialization" what do you mean?

Comment: @RyanP: There are dozens of Q&A here about this subject already. Not to mention the rest of the internet. And my fist comment here.

Comment: @Olaf i think you'll find that my updated function is perfectly idiomatic for reading a CBOR-encoded unsigned integer in the case that the value is greater than 23 (which I assume is the case the OP was asking about?)

Comment: @RichardHodges: Maybe. But there is no need for this distinction and complication if you use bitshifts in the first place. As I wrote, the compiler might very well optimise such a code up to a direct load for a target which support unaligned accesses like x86. Recommended practice is to leave optimisations to the toolchaln and don't do premature optimisations.

Comment: @Olaf I agree with you of course. Optimisations made on code that deserialises data off a network or disk are not likely to gain us much in reality. The reason I answered the question though, is that the OP had stepped on the common landmine of using a union, which almost always ends up being UB (strict aliasing), which people often don't know. I also thought the lesson on how the compiler handles memcpy was worth demonstrating.